# Webdriverio basic example webdriverio.addCommand.js does not work for me.

Tags: webdriver-io

I am a beginer with webdriverio.

I am trying to run its basic example webdriverio.addCommand.js . But seems it is also not working. It shows title was : Google. I am not understanding why it is not showing title of searched string. Could anyone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

```
  ...
  .title(function(err, res) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + res.value);
    })
...
```

According to https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/webdriverio.addCommand.js, it's taking a title of the page and then writes it to a console. Why should it show a searched string?